# How to create an NSDate that's in the user's local time for comparison (Swift2)?

Tags: swift2, nsdate, ios9

I need to create dates by altering the hours and minutes and compare it with the current date and time. This is to check if something is available (think calendar event). So I need to know if the current time is falling between start and end date window. How do I go about creating all 3 dates so that it's based on the user's local time? The reason it has to be local time is if they change their time zone, the comparison will still work. I know that NSDate is just a point of time, and when you view a new NSDate in the debugger, it displays as UTC. I need local time. What's the easiest way to go about creating these 3 dates for comparison? (please note that these dates do not need to be displayed on the UI, it's just for checking if an event is available)

Answer (score 0):

NSDate() will give you the current time and date. If you want to achieve your goal you need to create two NSDate objects representing the start and end of your start window (lets call them "start" and "end") and then run:

```
var current = NSDate()
if current.laterDate(end) == end && current.earlierDate(start) == start { //checks that end is after current and that start is before current
      //date is between start and end
} else {
    //date is before start or after end
}
```

Comment: How does this account for local time (user's time zone, DST)? When I view the date description in the debugger, it's in UTC.

Comment: You can use  current.descriptionWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale()) to get a string representation of the local time